# Regex not matching c++

Tags: c++, regex

I have this string to test:

```
"CPF char,
Nome char [80],
Idade int,
Salario double,
Sexo char,
Tem_Filhos bool,"
```

Or simply:

`string testStatement("CPF char,\nNome char [80],\nIdade int,\nSalario double,\nSexo char,\nTem_Filhos bool,");`

Here is my regEx:

`regex createTableInside("(?:[ \\n\\t]*)(\\w*)(?:[ \\n\\t]+)(?:(?:(char)[ \\n\\t]*\\[[ \\n\\t]*(\\d*)[ \\t\\n]*\\])|(char)|(int)|(double)|(bool)|(bloob))(?:[ \\n\\t]*)(,)");`

When i do a `regex_search`, it finds everything:

```
while(regex_search(testStatement, check, createTableInside))
{
    for(index = 1; index < check.size(); index++)
    {
        if(check.str(index).compare("") == 0) continue;

        cout << "\"" << check.str(index) << "\"" << endl;
    }

    aux = check.suffix();
}
```

Output:

```
"CPF"
"char"
","
"Nome"
"char"
"80"
","
"Idade"
"int"
","
"Salario"
"double"
","
"Sexo"
"char"
","
"Tem_Filhos"
"bool"
","
```

But when I do a `regex_match`, the `check.size()` always returns `0`.

I've tested my regEx here: https://www.debuggex.com/, and it works.

I've also tried the `match_any` constant:

```
regex_match(testStatement, check, createTableInside, match_any);
```

Whats wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Which compiler/library?

Comment: I'm using `#include <regex>` and the default mac osx g++ compiler

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could be that `regex_search()` will give you everything it possibly matches (groupwise), while `regex_match()` might want to match the **complete** input. Are you sure that the complete input matches the expression?

Comment: Maybe `regex_match` doesn't do sub-captures, so it just returns true or false, therefore no match info.

Comment: Put up the regex_match code you are using. And, it won't need a while(), just a if()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from the [docs (std::regex_search from cppreference.com)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search):

> `std::regex_search` will successfully match **any subsequence** of the given sequence, whereas `std::regex_match` will only return true if the regular expression matches the **entire** sequence.

You may want to inspect the [`std::match_results`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results), to check at which point exactly [`std::regex_match()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) has failed to match the complete sequence (see [`std::match_results::suffix()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/suffix) and [`std::match_results::prefix()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/prefix) members).

Comment: But it matches the entire sequence. I'm testing with http://regex101.com/#PCRE either. Using /g flag.

Comment: There are different regex engines, that may give you different results: _'online regex tester for **javascript, php, pcre and python**'_!

Comment: So why it is not matching in c++ ?

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano: it does not match the entire sequence. Surrounding your whole regex with `(?:`...`)+` would make it match the entire sequence.

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano Because there are different engines, as I mentioned. Also I'd recommend to use the regular regex character class shortcuts, such as '\w', etc.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ if I surround it with `(?: )+`, it will match only the last occurrence.. why?

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano - Even if you surround the regex with `(?: ..)+` the capture will only return the last set of ` ...,` each quantified itteration will overweite the capture groups each time. No regex flavor captures quantified itterations except for Dot-Net.

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano Test `match_results` as I recommended please! For details about the available regex grammars to use, and their exact defnitions you can refer to [`std::regex_constants::syntax_option_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I solved my problem splitting the string with `,` delimiter and then applying the `match_results`. Thanks!